# <td> onclick to submit a form

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am trying to click on td value to submit a form along with td value to be retrieve in servlet.I am getting null value .Kindly help

```
     <form id="simpleform" method="post" action="<portlet:actionURL/>"       name="simpleform">   

<table>


        <%  
        while(rs.next())
        { 
        %>
<tr> 
<td id="isTitles" onclick="document.simpleform.submit();">
        <%= rs.getString(1)%>
      </td>
      </tr>
        <% } %>
 </table>
        </form>
        <%
    }
```

and in servlet
    String myvalue=request.getParameter("isTitles");

Comment: try this : document.simpleform.submit();

Comment: hai @Sumitpatel I think am able to submit a form but i get null value in servlet String myvalue=request.getParameter("isTitles"); is this null value is due to form not submitted properly ??

Comment: if u r using the snippet pls provide a working sample. else just format it as code (4 space indent)

Comment: I don't see any form element named "isTitles". I think you are submitting an empty form. Not that <td> is not an element of the form, it's just part of the table.

Comment: isTitles is the id of <td>

Comment: need to submit a form based on <td> click along with td value to be retrieven in servlet @Plirkee

Comment: <td> is never sent to the server. only form elements like <input tpye="..."> are. On click you should set a value of such element (it could be hidden) with javascript and then submit.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer...

Answer (score 0):

try this javascript function that carries out the submitting

eg. in the form HTML:

```
<A HREF="http://page to go onto after click" onClick="submitForm('formName)">SEND</A>
```

in the Javascript

```
function submitForm(sub) {
document.forms[sub].submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment td is never sent to the server. 
In order to sent a value to the server side you should use form element. Here I use input type hidden. And on click I set the value of the element which will be sent to the server. So at the server side if value is 1 then td was clicked, is 0 then it wasn't

```
<form id="simpleform" method="post" action="<portlet:actionURL/>"       name="simpleform">   

<table>
        <input type="hidden" name="isTitles" id="isTitles" value="0"/>  

        <%  
        while(rs.next())
        { 
        %>
<tr> 
<td  onclick="document.getElementById('isTitles').value='1';document.simpleform.submit();">
        <%= rs.getString(1)%>
      </td>
      </tr>
        <% } %>
 </table>
        </form>
        <%
    }
```